# How to write 2 ip for one database?

Tags: java, oracle, configuration, datasource

I have datasource configuration file where i have `context` with `resource(s)`
like this

```
<Context>
     <Resource
        name="jdbc/pds"
        auth="Container"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        factory="myPackage.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"
        logAbandoned="true"
        maxTotal="30"
        maxIdle="10"
        maxWaitMillis="1000"
        password="encryptedPassword"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myFirstIP:port:MYDB"
        username="username"
        accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
    validationQuery="select 1 from dual" />
</Context>
```

My goal is to take data from base with the ip `myFirstIP` but if can not execute `validationQuery` with some reason , for example base is disabled, I want to take connect and take data from base with ip `mySecondIP`.
  I know that i can create second resource which has `mySecondIP` ip and check it on application side (in JAVA for me) if `myFirstIP` is disabled create connection with `mySecondIP`. But if I don't want additional checks on application side , can i make it using this configuration file to make default connection with `myFirstIP` and if it is disabled with `mySecondIP`?Is it possible ? If it is not possible what is best solution for my problem ?

I am using `oracle 11.2.0.2.0` , `java8` and `tomcat 8.5 / wildfly 9`

Comment: Take a look at this [using-dynamic-datasource-with-tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055357/using-dynamic-datasource-with-tomcat) ...it seems similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TNS keyword-value syntax with 2 or more address

```
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.10.10.88)(PORT = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.10.89)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = D88)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))(SERVER = DEDICATED)))";
```

Comment: where can i enter db_name here ?

Comment: if you know service_name then `(SERVICE_NAME = D88)` or  if ORACLE_SID  then `(SID = D88)`

Comment: syntax is like this i just need to change HOST and SERVICE_NAME  values and first Address will be default active ya ?

Comment: @Gog1nA  You need to change the `HOST` and the `SERVICE_NAME`.
The first address is used by default for the connection, if the first address does not have the required database `SERVICE_NAME` or the first address is not active, then try to connect to the second address.